# Autoconvolution vs Autocorrelation

Tags: convolution, autocorrelation

I have a serious doubt about `Autocorrelation` and `AutoConvolution`.
My understanding is,

### Autocorrelation

Autocorrelation is nothing but correlation of the signal and it's delayed version.
 Example : Autocorrelation of 2 functions f(t) & f(t+1).

### Autoconvolution

Autoconvolution is combination of  the two signals where the output signal will be a modified version of a signal in term of another signal with every point/unit.

### My Question

Are two signals are the same if their `auto-correlation functions` are the same?
Are two signals are the same if their `auto-convolution functions` are the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are two signals are the same if their `auto-convolution functions` are the same?

Not quite. Look at the autoconvolution in the frequency domain where the autoconvolution of $x$ (with itself) gives us $(X(f))^2$ in the frequency domain while the autoconvolution of $-x$ (with itself) gives us $(-X(f))^2 = (X(f))^2$. So, given an autoconvolution function, there are two (very related) signals $x$ and $-x$ that have the same autoconvolution function. But there are also many other signals that could have the same autoconvolution. Let $y(t)$ denote a signal such that $(Y(f))^2 = (X(f))^2$ holds *for every frequency $f$.* But it might be the case that, say, $Y(1) = X(1)$ while $Y(2) = -X(2)$ and $Y(e) = X(e)$ and $Y(\pi) = -X(\pi)$ etc giving us two vastly different signals $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ that have the same autoconvolution.

> Are two signals are the same if their `auto-correlation functions` are the same?

Not quite.  Now we are given $|X(f)|^2$ in the frequency domain and there are many different factorizations possible. For example, if $y(t)$ is a signal such that values taken in by its Fourier transform always lie on the unit circle in the complex plane (for every $f$, $|Y(f)|=1$) then $|X(f)Y(f)|^2 =  |X(f)|^2$ and so $x\star y$ has the same autocorrelation function as $x$. Note that $x(t)$ and $x(t-\tau)$ (which is a *delayed* version of $x(t)$) have the same autocorrelation function ($Y(f)$ happens to be $\exp(-j2\pi f \tau)$ here). Another factorization replaces $X(f)$ by $X^*(f)$ which tells us that $x(t)$ and $x(-t)$ (which is just $x(t)$ running backwards in time) have the same autocorrelation function.